# Does Azure provide a service like pubnub and pusher?

Tags: azure, pubnub

I'd like to know if Azure has a service similar to pubnub and pusher. I know I can use SignalR to provide real-time communication between the back and front end and [Notification Hub](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/notification-hubs/) to push to apps, but I'd like a more comprehensive solution like pubnub/pusher. For instance, [pubnub has clients for mobile AND web apps](https://www.pubnub.com/docs#all-sdks-home).

Could anyone shed some light here?

In case it helps, here's my setup:

[image]

So I have a server that notifies the iOS and Android apps, as well as the web app. Currently I'm using PushSharp to send push notifications to the apps and SignalR to send messages to the web app. I also use SignalR on my mobile apps.

Even though it's working I'd like a complete solution like pubnub. So does Azure provide such a service?

Comment: redis, azure storage queue, service bus, depending on what you need, perhaps event hub and notification hub

Comment: @4c74356b41 thanks for your comment, but in case of notification hub would it work for a javascript client? As far as I read it's intended for push notifications only, am I wrong? I also read a little bit about Service Bus, would it work with mobile apps? Thanks!

Comment: @4c74356b41 fair enough :) thank you anyway

Comment: This is very simple and very scalable using PubNub. Your web client simply subscribes to a channel(s) (and depending on the browser, you might be able to implement desktop notifications). For the mobile apps, same thing with subscribing to channels but you would also register the device for push notifications on those channels with PubNub. (to be continued...)

Comment: When you publish a message, you include an APNS and GCM payload and the devices will either receive the realtime message via PubNub subscribe or the push notification via APNS or GCM because the PubNub Network also sent the message to those services to be delivered to the registered devices - easy peasy. See [Sending APNS and GCM Messages to Subscribers and Mobile Push Notification Services in One API Call](https://support.pubnub.com/support/discussions/topics/14000006344), for more details on this. Another PubNub resource may reply with a more formalized and complete answer.

Comment: @CraigConover thank you, I know it's easier with PubNub, I have been using the free tier. The problem remains with the price table. Because of the BizSpark program I'm entitled to use Azure's services free of charge up to a usage limit, with PubNub I'd have to spend 50USD extra... That's why I was looking for an Azure solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be a short reply to your post. The answer is "No". :-)

You are currently using the best approach by combining push notifications to your mobile apps, and SignalR for your web app. There is no current Azure service offering that will allow you to send realtime notifications to both.

Source: Azure nerd and also have a situation exactly like yours where our team has to push notifications to Android, iOS, and connected web clients.

Comment: Hey Rob, thank you for the answer. That's sad :/ so my only chances at a really global RT experience (dev-side) would be pubnub/pusher and similars, right?

Comment: Yes - you're going to have to rely on something else other than Azure services to do so. I'm in the same boat as you are, and would love to see something introduced to make my life easier in this regard as well. But SignalR + Notification Hubs aren't terrible.

Comment: I know they're not, I have been using this setup since 2014, but  the problem is that with time it becomes a far more complex code to maintain than if using a centralized solution like the aforementioned. Anyway, thank you for your help, at least I can give up for now :(

Comment: This was in 2017 - is there any Azure service now in Azure like Pusher ?

Comment: Sort of, but it's not because Azure introduced a service. You can use browser based service workers to subscribe to and listen for push notifications. Then you can use Notification Hub for both mobile and web apps.

Answer (score 3):

PubNub now provides a gateway into Azure via the "PubNub Realtime Gateway for Azure Event Hubs".

It lets you use PubNub realtime data streams easily with Azure via Event Hub proxies into the Azure Cloud.  Check out the README for the quickstart template here:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/pubnub-eventhub-bridge

And if you're interested in a more formal walkthrough of how to use it, don't hesitate to ping us at support@pubnub.com, the email will get routed my way and I'd be happy to help discuss further and help you customize it for your use case.